# is it correct to say "Why are you twitching your eyes"?

Tags: word-usage

My friend has a weak eyesight and is unable to see properly. Whenever he has to read something, he contracts his eyes.

Suppose I want to ask him about this habit, is *twitch* the proper word to use in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

No, if I understand you correctly, what your friends does (contracting the eyes) to see better,the word you are looking for is [**squint**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/squint).

> He squints to try and read the small print.

Twitching would be a very quick, usually involuntary contracting of muscles around the eye, as if he were blinking his eyes in a kind of exaggerated manner.

Comment: Squint is the word :) Thanks. One more thing which is not related to my question but to the text of my question - Is " I asked this my friend" correct? It sounds kind of incomplete to me

Comment: Actually, I think the sentence is indeed incomplete. I will edit your question. :)

Comment: You corrected my sentence but I want to know what my mistake was. What's wrong "I asked <this*> my friend"? Did I have to use some kind of preposition? I think something's wrong with <this*>.

Comment: The difficulty is that you didn't specify exactly _what_ you would ask. You could say "I asked my friend this:" or "I asked my friend about this:", _followed_ by an explanation of _what_ you asked. I found it in this case better readable to first mention what you ask about and then refer back to it. Apart from that, you would say "I asked my friend this" and not "I asked this my friend". If it is still unclear, you could ask about it in a separate question :)

Comment: "I asked my friend this" will do.

Comment: +1 As a healthcare provider, I always thought squint is strabismus! Thanks again for introducing *squint* as a non-medical term. :)